# Androidannotations: Classes can not be resolved when from different package on clean build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-annotations

If I am doing a clean build I get a compile error when I am using an annotated activity that's not in the same package as the activity I am currently in.

Let me give an example: I have this activity `com.example.packageA.A`:

```
@EActivity
public class A extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        B_.intent(this).start();
    }
}
```

and this activity `com.example.packageB.B`:

```
@EActivity
public class B extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

}
```

When I am doing a clean build I'll get the following compile error: B_ cannot be resolved
As soon as I change anything in A and save it the error disappears.

The error does not occur if both activities are in the same package. All classes are generated in .apt_generated folder.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in a new project. So it seems to have to do with some project specific settings. Let me know if you need further details.

Any hints and tips are highly appreciated because it's very annoying to go through all classes, add a space and save it to get rid of all errors I have after eclipse startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very well known issue of AA with Eclipse. As said in the project's [FAQ page](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FAQ#wiki-import), you can fix it by either :

- Importing the whole package: `import com.example.packageB.*;`
- Using a fully qualified name : `com.example.packageB.B_.intent(this).start();`
- Having `A` and `B_` in the same package.

Comment: Hmm, I was searching all over the place, but didn't find the FAQ page. Thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: Feedbacks are welcome to improve wiki. If you have some suggestions, I'll be happy to hear them.